# How to draw a string with a circle in the middle, circle at the end?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I want to draw some digram like this and no idea how to draw the circle in the middle and at the edge of string.

[image]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it looks like a "do it for me" question and this type of questions is not well regarded here and does not receive too much attention unless somebody volunteers to provide a solution. Adding a code snippet with what you have so far usually helps attracting more answers.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! See "Minimal introduction to TikZ (unofficial)" documentation available on https://ctan.org/pkg/pgf?lang=en.

Answer (score 1):

Only for the string and the circle (but I love physics):

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw[] ((0,0)--(2,0) (2.5,0) circle(0.5);
        \draw (0,2)--(1.5,2) (2.0,2) circle(.5) (2.5,2) --(4,2);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

A solution with a node in a shape of a circle.

[image: node at end, in the middle]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14]{standalone}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
        circ/.style = {
            circle, 
            draw, 
            fill = white, 
            inner sep = 0pt, 
            minimum size = 1cm
            }
        ]
        \draw (0,0) --++ (4,0) node[circ] {};
        \draw (0,-2) --++ (4,0) node[circ, pos=0.5] {};     
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```